# Consulta por índice em coluna do tipo JSON

Tags: mysql

Como realizo uma consulta, por índice, onde os dados da coluna são do tipo JSON?

Por exemplo:

Desejo obter todos os dados onde a tensão for igual à 220:

*tabela* **material**

```
id | descricao   | extra
 2 | Altus       | {"tensao": "220", "comunicacao": "2"}
 5 | Sonesse 406 | {"tensao": "110", "comunicacao": "2"}
 7 | Sonesse 409 | {"tensao": "220", "comunicacao": "2"}
```

Comment: Sendo o 5.7 creio que tenha muita coisa https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html, creio que possa usar `JSON_CONTAINS` / `JSON_EXTRACT`, desde que o tipo da coluna seja `JSON`. Agora eu sinceramente diria que o melhor seria criar colunas ou até uma estrutura relacional ao invés de salvar como JSON "puro".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que você possa usar [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html), mas se for do tipo JSON já pode fazer assim:

```
... WHERE `extra`->'$.tensao' = 200
```

Pode também usar o `JSON_CONTAINS`, algo como:

```
... WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`extra`, 200, '$.tensao')
```

Não cheguei a testar `JSON_CONTAINS` com colunas que não sejam do tipo `JSON`.

---

### Extra:

Se tratando de um banco simples, não vejo problema algum em usar JSON, agora se supondo que o banco precise fazer consultas complexas, talvez deva optar por não usar JSON, mas sim uma estrutura relacional divido (conforme a necessidade) para poder fazer comparações e extrações de dados.

Por exemplo um estoque tem X produtos, todos produtos compartilham daquele valor, logo seria interessante haver uma tabela para valores e outra para produtos, seria uma estrutura `N:N` (many-to-many).

Aproveite e leia sobre o `JOIN`: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/3635)