# Como realizar consulta de dados aninhados em coluna do tipo JSON

Tags: mysql

Possuo os dados (aninhados) abaixo em uma coluna do tipo JSON:

```
[{"modSelecionado": "13"}, {"modSelecionado": "15"}, {"modSelecionado":
 "16"}, {"supMaxima": "5,00", "tensaoMotor": "1", "comunicacaoMotor": "1"}]
```

Como realizo uma consulta, para saber por exemplo se **supMaxima** é maior ou igual à um determinado valor?

Comment: Isso não foi respondido na pergunta de sexta-feira?

Comment: Olá @LINK, a estrutura dos dados que estão armazenados na coluna é diferente.

Comment: Tente o seguinte: SELECT * FROM `Tabela` 
WHERE coluna->"$.supMaxima" > 5;

Comment: Olá @CaiqueRomero, repare que a estrutura é diferente [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247576/consulta-por-%C3%ADndice-em-coluna-do-tipo-json), ou seja, não funciona. =\